# Gesture recognizer not responding

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uitapgesturerecognizer

I have a button on my view controller that brings in a menu and a slightly transparent view `blackView` behind it - the menu class includes a tap gesture recognizer to dismiss the menu when `blackView` is tapped. However it's not responding, and I'm not sure where my problem is. Here's the code for the menu:

```
class MenuController: NSObject, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

let blackView = UIView()

let collectionView: UICollectionView = {

    let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    let cv = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
    cv.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    return cv
}()

let cellId = "cellId"


func presentMenu() {

    if let window = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow {

        blackView.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0, alpha: 0.5)
        blackView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        // Tap outside to dismiss
        blackView.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleDismiss)))

        window.addSubview(blackView)
        window.addSubview(collectionView)

        let height: CGFloat = 200
        let y = window.frame.height - height
        collectionView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: window.frame.height, width: window.frame.width, height: height)

        blackView.frame = window.frame
        blackView.alpha = 0

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 1, initialSpringVelocity: 1, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {
            self.blackView.alpha = 1

            self.collectionView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: y, width: self.collectionView.frame.width, height: self.collectionView.frame.height)

            }, completion: nil)
    }
}


func handleDismiss() {
    print("working")

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5) {
        self.blackView.alpha = 0
        if let window = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow {

            self.collectionView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: window.frame.height, width: self.collectionView.frame.width, height: self.collectionView.frame.height)

        }
    }
}


// Collection view data sources
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 3
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath)
    return cell
}



override init() {
    super.init()

    collectionView.dataSource = self
    collectionView.delegate = self

    collectionView.register(MenuCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: cellId)
}



}
```

`presentMenu` is called and the menu appears when I tap the necessary button on my view controller. But `handleDismiss` is not getting called. Thanks for any help hopefully this is just a beginner mistake!

EDIT after solution: I was initializing `menuController()` in my view controller like so:

```
func showMenu() {
    let menuController = MenuController()

    menuController.presentMenu()

}
```

And changing it to @ronatory's solution of

```
lazy var menuController: MenuController = {
  let menuController = MenuController()
  return menuController
}()

func showMenu() {
  menuController.presentMenu()
}
```

Solved it.

Comment: is there a reason that you need to change the frame of the menu every time you use it?

Comment: I am just thinking that logically it would make sense to initialize the menu earlier on, and just keep the `animate` code in the `present()` and `dismiss()` functions

Comment: Can you show the rest of the class? Especially how you create the `collectionView`?

Comment: And, if I understand your logic correctly, you are presenting both a menu and a view separately to achieve the menu view look? This isn't a great way to go about this. It would make more sense to add the collection view to the view you are presenting.

Comment: Could you share your project on GitHub or something? That would make it MUCH easier to help you, if you were to need it

Comment: @ronatory I edited my post to show the whole class

Comment: @RyanCocuzzo I'll share the project if need be, I was hoping it would be a simple newbie error and I could fix it. I'll dropbox it in a bit.

Comment: I tested your code and for me it worked, would be really nice if you can share the project to see whats wrong

Comment: Yea im checking it out, one sec

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the only way I found out was to change the initialization of your `menuController`. Instead of initializing it in the `showMenu()` method (the problem is that you initialize it in the method and after the method is executed menuController is nil):

```
func showMenu() {
    let menuController = MenuController()
    menuController.presentMenu()
}
```

Replace it with using a **lazy stored property** (to also have access to the instance after the method is executed) and there is also no need to set `blackView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true`. You can delete it:

```
lazy var menuController: MenuController = {
  let menuController = MenuController()
  return menuController
}()

func showMenu() {
  menuController.presentMenu()
}
```

That's all. After this change your tap gesture recognizer should work. I tested it with your project. It would be nice if you add this part of your project to the question as code, so others can understand better the problem without needing to download the project

Comment: That worked, thanks! Do you know exactly why the gesture recognizer wasn't working when `menuController` was initialized within the `showMenu()` function?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but in my opinion the reason why my solution with the lazy stored property and Ryan Cocuzzo's solution works with instantiating the menuController as class property is, that if you instantiate menuController at first in the method, there the initialization is not really complete and this might lead to the problem that you can't really use MenuController, you see it also that you didn't see the 3 cells with your initial implementation. Anyway I just would currently prefer the lazy stored property way, so that the `menuController` is first initialized when you really need it

Answer (score 1):

So, it took me a bit but here is the full class now (Working and all) :) Happy Coding!

```
import UIKit


class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let menuController = MenuController()


    // ******************    // ******************    // ******************    // ******************    // ******************


    func showMenu() {



        menuController.presentMenu()
        let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(MenuController.handleDismiss))

        MenuController.blackView.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
      self.view.addSubview(MenuController.blackView)


    }

    // ******************    // ******************    // ******************    // ******************    // ******************


    func handleDismiss() {
        menuController.handleDismiss()
        if MenuController.blackView.alpha != 0 {

        }
    }




}


class MenuController: NSObject, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

    static let blackView = UIView()



    func presentMenu() {

        if let window = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow {

            MenuController.blackView.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0, alpha: .5)
            MenuController.blackView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
            // Tap outside to dismiss


            window.addSubview(MenuController.blackView)

            let height: CGFloat = 200
            let y = window.frame.height - height
            collectionView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: window.frame.height, width: window.frame.width, height: height)

            MenuController.blackView.frame = window.frame
            MenuController.blackView.alpha = 0

            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 1, initialSpringVelocity: 1, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {
                MenuController.blackView.alpha = 1

                self.collectionView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: y, width: self.collectionView.frame.width, height: self.collectionView.frame.height)

                }, completion: nil)
        }
    }


    func handleDismiss() {
        print("working")

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5) {
            MenuController.blackView.alpha = 0
            if let window = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow {

                self.collectionView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: window.frame.height, width: self.collectionView.frame.width, height: self.collectionView.frame.height)

            }
        }
    }



}
```

Comment: I know you found an answer, but please I would really appreciate an upvote because this took me a bit to solve

Comment: Thanks! I'll definitely give an up vote, but please just keep the relevant changes you made and not the whole class. And please remove the info at the top with my name and the project name.

Comment: Yea ill get that rn I didnt realize that haha

Comment: Ok @KingTim I removed everything that is not pretty important

Comment: Not a problem at all!